# How does .valid? run even there is no object in front of it (valid? instead of object.valid?)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Watching Railscasts, more specifically Form Objects. Here is the code.

Controller code:

```
def create
  @signup_form = SignupForm.new
  if @signup_form.submit(params[:user])
    session[:user_id] = @signup_form.user.id
    redirect_to @signup_form.user, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Method found on form object:

```
  class SignupForm 
    def submit(params)
      user.attributes = params.slice(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
      profile.attributes = params.slice(:twitter_name, :github_name, :bio)
      self.subscribed = params[:subscribed]
      if valid?
        generate_token
        user.save!
        profile.save!
        true
      else
        false
      end
    end
  end
```

I understand most of the code, but what I don't understand is how `.valid?` can run without an object written directly in front of it (i.e.: `object.valid?`)? I tried replicating this with Ruby, but Ruby requires an object to be directly written in front of the method, which leads me to believe this is some sort of Rails magic.

Can someone explain how `.valid?` runs without an object in front of it , and which object it picks up?

I tried using the following Ruby code and did not work:

```
array = [1,2,3,4]

def meth
  if is_a?
    puts "is array"
  else
    puts "not array"
  end
end

array.meth => error: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused: you are calling `puts` without a receiver, you are calling `render` without a receiver, you are calling `params` without a receiver, you are calling `generate_token` without a receiver, and I assume you have already seen `attr_accessor`, `attr_reader`, `attr_writer`, `require`, and some others. So, why does `valid?` in particular bother you?

Comment: That reason why it confused me a little bit is that I'm used to seeing `object.valid?` being used, and not seeing that confused me. For `params` `render`, although I am not aware of how Rails internally implements them, I have not seen an example of an object being explicitly called on them (i.e.: controller_instance.params). I have only seen the method being called, sometimes with arguments being passed in them (`render("new")`), but never with an object in front of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [the Railscast #416 in question](http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects), Ryan includes (among others) the `ActiveModel::Validations` module into the `SignupForm` class. This module [implements](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F) the `valid?` method for the class.

Now, in Ruby you can always call methods on the current object (i.e. `self`) without explicitly naming the receiver. If the receiver is unnamed, `self` is always assumed. Thus, in your `submit` method, `valid?` in called on the same instance of the `SubmitForm` where you originally called `submit` on.

Comment: I tried passing an object to a method without explicitly naming it in the if statement and it didn't work (see edited question above).

Comment: @the12 Your error was because you supplied `is_a?` with the wrong number of arguments. It expects one argument e.g. `is_a?(Array)`. You should know there is no "Rails magic", it is all just Ruby

Answer (score 0):

```
 class SignupForm 

   def submit(params)
     user.attributes = params.slice(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
     profile.attributes = params.slice(:twitter_name, :github_name, :bio)
     self.subscribed = params[:subscribed]
     if valid?
       generate_token
       user.save!
       profile.save!
       true
     else
       false
     end
   end

   def valid? // <--- this is what they are calling.
     return true   // this is made up... i am sure it does something
   end
 end
```